# where to change color of the statusbar during startup when Default.png is displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, startup, splash-screen, statusbar

I have an app that sets the statusbar color like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    ...
}
```

Yet during startup when my Default.png is displayed a grey status bar is displayed.

I'd like to know how to display the black style also on startup...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are looking to change it once and only once, the best place to do this is in your application's plist.

You can add:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent</string>
```

or if viewing as Property List

```
Status bar style          Translucent black style
```

Just right click and "Add row", Status bar style will be an available option, with Translucent black style as the available field.

Comment: Better answer than my lazy phone typed one. Deleting!

Comment: You here faster of about 80 seconds. also deleting :)